# Ubuntu 20.04.1 desktop screen resolution on parallels VM

Tags: 20.04, screen, parallels

I recently installed Ubuntu 20 on my parallels virtual machine but can't figure out how to fix the resolution. If I make it full screen, it is a box in the middle that doesn't take up much as black borders on both sides. When I was running Ubuntu 18, it would size dynamically just fine but I can't figure out why it isn't doing that anymore. I have the graphic resolution settings set to scaled.

Any help would be appreciated!